# Proving the relationship between 2 intervals

Tags: integration, normed-spaces

Let n be a non-zero natural number, and p a real number, both fixed.

Let $M_k$ ={$x\in R^n | 4^k<=||x||<4^{k+1}$} and $I_k=\int\limits_{M_k} ||x||^p |d^nx|$ for any natural k.

Prove that there is a real $\alpha$ (in terms of n and p) such that $I_6=\alpha I_1$.

I don't really know how to go on about this exercise. Any hints on how to get started?

Comment: What does $|d^n x|$ mean?? It is straightforward to see that $I_1 >0$ and $I_k $ is finite so such an $\alpha$ must exist.

Comment: Well, since $x\in R^n$, the integration is done n times like how you would integrate a $x\in R^2$ with |$dx_1$||$dx_2$|, and the |  | is there to show that the orientation of integration does not matter.

Comment: Usually one writes $dx$.

Answer (score 0):

$I_1> 0$ so we can take $\alpha =\frac {I_6} {I_1}$. This proves existence of $\alpha =\alpha (n,p)$. If you want to explicitly compute $\alpha$ use polar coordinates: Exercise 6 in the chapter on On Integration on Product Spaces in Rudin's RCA.

Comment: But how do I show what the value of $\alpha$ is in terms of n and p, so that the equality holds?